# How to add a view shared by intent in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-view

I shared a custome view with 'intent'. I got it in the second activity with "getSerializableExtra".

I can't add this view in my layout. I think it's a problem of "context" :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();  

int nbTextView = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER, 0);   

MyTextView[] text= (MyTextView[]) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);


this.myLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProp2);  

myLayout.addView(text[0]); // I think this part is a problem
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Forgot : "Hello every one, ..."

Answer (score 1):

> I shared a custome view with 'intent'.

That is not practical, sorry.

> I can't add this view in my layout

You should have crashed. Regardless:

- A `View` is tied to the activity that created it
- Passing things via an `Intent` makes copies, so the `View` that your second activity received at best is a copy of the `View` that the first activity had

Comment: I had to implement Serializable in my custom view: 
public class MyTextView extends TextView implements Serializable

The application crashed but since I implements Serializable in my class it does not crash.

Comment: @Haydens: "I had to implement Serializable in my custom view" -- yes, and that is not going to work, as there are plenty of fields in a `View` that cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

As *CommonsWare* said, I think you may

1. pass serializable/parcelable **data** what you assign to your **View** From  **FirstActivity** with Intent

   (like name, age, url or whatever..)
2. retrieve **data** from **SecondActivity**
3. generate a new **View** with data
4. add this **View** to where you want

=== **Supplement** ===

and you may want to retrieve **data** to **FirstActivity** from SecondActivity
then just pass it by ***setResult()*** in **SecondActivity**
and get it on ***onActivityResult()*** in **FirstActivity**

Comment: It's what i have done. I get data in the second activity with : 
MyTextView[] text = (MyTextView[]) Intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);

but I can't add it to my Layout. This line does not work :
this.myLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProp2);
myLayout.addView(text[0]);

Comment: I mean the `data` in your TextView instead of TextView, such as `"Robert"` in your TextView, then I pass `"Robert"` to next activity.

Comment: I did that with a custom class. Thank you very much.